# Invalid Swift Support in post processing with Codemagic

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, codemagic

I´m trying to upload an app with Codemagic and it goes wrong in the post processing stage App Store distribution, after almost 30 tries to find a build matching uploaded version yet, says this:

> The application binary was successfully uploaded to App Store Connect for processing but the corresponding build is not available in App Store Connect. This usually happens when the uploaded application has one or more issues. Please check your email for direct feedback from Apple.

And they send me a mail saying:

"Swift Support it´s invalid: The SwiftSupport floder is missing. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it."

I tried changing the "Embedded Content Contains Swift Code", the "BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION" and the "DEFINES_MODULE" fields but nothing change. Don´t know if its a problem of Codemagic or Apple.

Comment: did you manage to solve it? same issue here!

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this error with Codemagic, in my case I was using an invalid profile to submit to the AppStore. I was trying to upload iOS build to TestFlight using AdHoc distribution profile. But for TestFlight the AppStore distribution profile must be used.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the version code and uploading again, it happened to me too. However, uploading a new build seemed to work without issues. App Store Connect team revealed that there was a brief issue where some apps received this error.

You can read other developer's experiences on the Apple Developer forums at [this link](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/677738)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).